# How to style a standard GWT component (TabBar) differently?

Tags: css, gwt

I am using a TabBar and I want to style the component in different ways. So one time this style, another time that style. I thought this will work but it didn't:

```
TabBar t = new TabBar();
t.addTab( "1" );
t.addTab( "2" );
t.addStyleName( MyResources.INSTANCE.css().slickTab() );
```

And:

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle
{
 public static final MyResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyResources.class);
 @Source("style.css") MyCssResource css();
}
public interface MyCssResource extends CssResource
{
 String slickTab();
}
```

In the CSS

```
.slickTab .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

But the appearance don't change. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to force this in CSS.

```
.slickTab .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Also, since you're adding a style which is subject to the parent style. If this is the case, you might need to set 'setStylePrimaryName' instead of adding it and toggle between style changes with handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS. `.slickTab .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem` will match a TabBarItem inside a TabBar inside a slickTab. However, since the TabBar *is* the slickTab, and is not *inside* it, you need to do something like this (note .gwt-TabBar.slickTab):

```
.gwt-TabBar.slickTab .gwt-TabBarItem {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface MyCssResource need to be inside MyResources.

Here's an exemple :

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle
{
    public static final Resources INSTANCE = 
        GWT.create( Resources.class );

    /***********************************************
     *                    Home
     ***********************************************/
    @Source( "./css/home.css" )
    public HomeCss getHomeCss();

    public interface HomeCss extends CssResource
    {
         String loginBtn();
    }

    /***********************************************
     *                Another Page
     ***********************************************/
    @Source( "./css/AnotherPage.css" )
    public AnotherPage getAnotherPageCss();

    public interface AnotherPage extends CssResource
    {
         String title();
    }
}
```

This is the way I use all kind of Resource and it work really well.
Whenever you need to use it many time in the same method or function, you can do this :

```
HomeCss homeStyle = Resource.INSTANCE.getHomeCss();
yourPanel.setStyleName( homeStyle.yourPanel() );
```

Don't hesitate to ask if there's anything you didn't understand.

Comment: No, thats not the issue here. All my CSS works great for other stuff.

Comment: Re looking at your code, I think it might be cause by using ".slickTab .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem " in your CSS. I've tried that too in the past and it hadn't work. You'll need so separate them and assign them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

`.slickTab .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem` is going to match something with class gwt-TabBarItem inside something with class gwt-TabBar inside something with class slickTab. I think you just want `.slickTab .gwt-TabBarItem` for the CSS selector.

I highly recommend using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the HTML structure generated by GWT and how your CSS selectors are applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

t.addStyleName( MyResources.INSTANCE.css().slickTab() );

Modifies the class element attribute. And INSTANCE.css().slickTab() does not do what you think. These methods without annotations bring back to java the @def's in the css. To make what you want add to MyCssResource:

```
@ClassName("slickTab")
String slickTab();
```

So, when GWT garbles the css upside down that method will return the corect class, ej "awEs". These GWT guys are obsessive about squeezing stuff :)

And remember, firebug & chrome-inspector are your friends.