# Customized combobox text in HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, select, combobox

I wonder if it is possible to create combo box as in the picture below. The aim is that the actual text of the combo (*select* in *HTML*) would be different that items' texts that are displayed while the combo is opened.

[ComboBox view http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/8223/pagetitle.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/8223/pagetitle.png)

The application is written using [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) so any solution in [gwt](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) or *HTML/JavaScript* would be great.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox is actually a component from GWT-EXT (which I personally never used) so they might have their own way to do it.
In the classic GWT way though, you would do something like :
`comboBox.getCell(X).setStyleName( style.thisStringStyle );`

For this, you'd need to have your CSS accessible through ClientBundle (for an exemple see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942640/how-to-style-a-standard-gwt-component-tabbar-differently/2943697#2943697)).

Answer (score -1):

CSS can be used to give such effect, but browser compatibility will be an issue.

Comment: Could you be more precise? How do you think it is possible to set different strings for combobox text and the items using CSS?

Comment: You want to assign strings using css?

Comment: I think he means that the select is just cropping the selected option.

Comment: Sorry guys for the late response. Ya, I meant the cropping of the combo box only. I am not thinking of chopping off from the entries or appending something to the entries in the combo box. But just the make the drop down list bigger using CSS.